# How to resolve a URLinto an IP (v4), port in ActionScript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, url, ip, resolver

I look for something alike `boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver` that would take a url like `google.com` in and return a list of IP adresses and ports pairs mapped to that URL. How to do such thing in ActionScript3?

Comment: Why not just contact the Domain Name Server and get the info?

Comment: And pretty sure it will all only be on port 80